# Как получить доступ к полям классов

Tags: java, ооп, hibernate

Помогите разобраться в этом сложном для меня моменте. У меня есть два класса сущностей `User` и `Hotel`, у них поля `long id` и геттеры. Пара классов `UserDAO`, `HotelDAO` которые наследуются от общего `GeneralDAO<T>` в нём метод `public T save(T t)`.  Логика у метода следующая, сохранять объект, если у него `id` равен `0`, то есть `if(t.getId() == 0)` то сохраняю объект в базу данных. Объясните пожалуйста, как я могу получить доступ к полям классов `User` и `Hotel`,чтобы использовать их в `GeneralDAO<T>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать общий класс `MyEntity` с полем `long id` + геттеры/сеттеры.

Унаследовать свои классы `User` и `Hotel` от класса `MyEntity`.

`GeneralDAO<T>` перестроить на `GeneralDAO<T extends MyEntity>`

**Приблизительная структура классов:**

```
class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

class GeneralDAO<T extends MyEntity> {

    public T save(T t) {
        if (t.getId() == 0) {
            //TODO: som
        }
        return t;
    }
}

class User extends MyEntity{

}

class Home extends MyEntity{

}
```

Comment: Chubatiy, сделал всё так, но почему-то при вызове в методе геттера нет, а получается `t.id` ... я что-то не так делаю ? Почему не `t.getId()` ?

Comment: @YuriiS а сам метод точно находится в классе `MyEntity` и у него модификатор доступа `public` ?

Comment: MrFylypenko, да `package hibernate_dz.dz_lesson4.model;

public class IdEntity {
    
    public long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}`

Comment: Добавил приблизительную структуру классов

Comment: Chubatiy, есть `getId()`... что-то со мной не то, смотрю и не вижу (((